# Sprite size issue across web browsers

Tags: css, svg, css-sprites, units-of-measurement, background-size

I have a issue with css sprite size across different web browsers. Some of the icons looks like another icon, laying underneath is displayed. There are sections where the same code shows differently the same icon on the web page.

Is this unit calculation problem? What is - in your - opinion best practise to resize sprite? Thanks for a discussion and your help!

HTML

```
<h1>Wideo</h1>
```

CSS

```
section h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.9375rem;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: -0.0375rem;
  line-height: 1.625rem;
  word-break: break-word;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 1.25rem 1.5625rem;
}

section h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  left: -40px;
  font-size: 0.9375rem;
}
```

SPRITE CSS

```
section h1:before {
  background-position: 0em -75.7em;
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 2.2em;
}
section h1:before {
  content: '';
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url(../svg/sprite.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 24em 82em;
}
```

Best regards,

Kuba